# How to trigger model to update the lists it is linked to

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

`self.viewA` is `QListView` and it gets populated via its `QAbstractTableModel` object-instance. `QAbstractTableModel` object-instance gets its data from a globally declared `items` list variable. Later `items` data-list-variable gets modified (data added). On a such data-list-variable change I want to trigger an `QAbstractTableModel` so it goes ahead and updates `QListView` with the new items. So far the only way I am aware of to trigger `QAbstractTableModel` is to emit signal:

```
myQListView.model().emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())
```

I've also tried:

```
myQListView.model().reset()
```

but that doesn't help. So the question is how to update QListView when data-variable used by QListView model gets modified?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

items=['Item 0','Item 1','Item 2']

class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(items)
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(items[index.row()])
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return key

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 
        model=ListModel()

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(model) 

        button=QtGui.QPushButton('Add Item')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)
        self.show()

    def onClick(self, index):
        items.append('Item %s'%len(items))
        self.viewA.model().emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())
        # self.viewA.model().reset()

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 approaches one of which should be implemented every time you use Model-View.

**Model as a data storage**

- Put your variable `items` into `ListModel`. Modify items using methods of `ListModel`.
  For example, to append a row you can use methods of `QAbstractItemModel` :  `insertRow` and then `setData`.
- Reimplement `insertRows`: call `beginInsertRows` add new rows into `items` and call `endInsertRows`.
- Reimplement `removeRows`
- Reimplement `setData` and emit signal `dataChanged` appropriately.
- Also you can add new methods to the model for easy usage: `appendData`...

**Model as an adapter**

Here is a theory: https://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/13/28/view
This approach requires more code, but it's more reliable and extendable.

- Create a new class inherited from `QObject` and put `items` there. Create methods to modify items from outside. Emit signals `itemAboutToBeAdded`, `itemAdded`, `itemAboutToBeRemoved`, `itemRemoved`, `itemChanged`...
- Subscribe the model to signals of the new class and call appropriate methods: `beginInsertRows`, `endInsertRows`, `beginRemoveRows`, `endRemoveRows`, `emit dataChanged`...

Why these two approaches? Because model should be syncronized with the data. If you can modify the data outside the model you can get a lot of problems.

Comment: In my example `items` data-variable is declared and modified outside of `ListModel`. `ListModel` simply points to this variable. The model itself doesn't create any `QListView` "items". The model simply reads `QModelIndex` row and column number. And depending on how `.data()` method is set returns an associated value stored in `items` data-variable. I write it here to verify I understand it correctly.... Now knowing what the model is it is quite unclear why then would we need all those `model` methods: `itemAboutToBeAdded, itemAdded and etc. Please explain.

Comment: It would be great if you post an example code to illustrate your idea on how `model` should be implemented (using `beginInsertRows`, `itemAboutToBeAdded`) If now I am the only one who is interested in this subject later others would appreciate it too.

Comment: "items data-variable is declared and modified outside of ListModel". That's why I said that this approach is wrong and shouldn't be used. Put `items` inside the model and don't change it from outside. In this case all these methods will be used to notify those why use the model that data is chagned.

Comment: Regarding your question "why itemAboutToBeAdded, itemAdded are needed". It's a critical requirement of Model-View in Qt. For example, views store indexes before the change and then restore them.

Comment: Actually the previous comment was about `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`. `itemAboutToBeAdded` etc. are needed only for the second approach when you have a class-storage. It should notify the model that the data is changed.